# Flutter assets error: EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

flutter can not find my images assets, what can I be doing wrong?

I got the error on debugger:

Launching lib/main.dart on XT1097 in debug mode...
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.

```
I/flutter (  876): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞══
I/flutter (  876): Unable to load asset: assets/images/user/background.jpg
I/flutter (  876): "assets/images/user/background.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

My pubspec.yml:

```
environment:
    sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
    sqflite: any
    path_provider: '>=0.3.0'
    charts_flutter: any
    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    material_search: ^0.2.8
    dio: ^1.0.3
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter


flutter:
    uses-material-design: true
    assets:
        - assets/images/
```

and the code:

```
                new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    decoration : BoxDecoration(
                        image: new DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/user/background.jpg'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    accountName: new Text('Diego Botelho'),
                    accountEmail: new Text('dibmartins@gmail.com'),
                    currentAccountPicture: new GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => print('Toque na imagem'),
                        child: new CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/user/avatar.png'),
                        )
                    )
                ),
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know currently only files directly placed under the registered directory are added to assets.

This should work:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
   - assets/images/
   - assets/images/user/
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how this resolved for me.

Previously I was using the exact paths to images as suggested

```
 assets:
 - assets/logo_linked_in.jpg
 - assets/logo_medium.png
 - assets/logo_stackoverflow.png
 - assets/myself.jpg
 - assets/sparta.jpg
 - assets/fox.png
```

Then I tried just the parent directory name, which was just using:

```
assets:
 - assets/
```

Voila! It worked like a charm!

I hope this helps someone.

**P.S. - For newbies like me:**

Make sure you have correctly indented the `pubspec.yaml`
as this is very important for the build.

Comment: Tinkering the pubspec.yaml alignment seems to have solved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have to correct the alignments between my **assets** and the **uses-material-design** lines in pubspec.yaml.

```
flutter:
    uses-material-desgin: true
    assets:
        - images/3.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall app on device/emulator
Run flutter clean.
Run app

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. In my case it was because the emulator of the phone that I am using does not have access to the internet.

Run the application on a physical mobile device and it worked immediately.

Solution connect the emulator to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have two space between _ and assets that's why this exception coming

```
-  assets/images/logo.png
-  assets/images/bg.jpg
```

Now I fixed by

```
assets:
- assets/images/logo.png
- assets/images/bg.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while i was using relative path like that `Image.asset('./../images/welcome.png')`, it doesn't work.

But if i use absolute path like that `Image.asset('images/welcome.png')`, it works !

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when i was accidentally passing number parameter as URL to get image from server.

```
leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
      ),
```

//imageUrl should be correct image url not other type.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case I was in hot reload mode and nothing was happening. I had to click hot restart for the image to show up.

[image: Hot Restart]

Answer (score 0):

if  web app not loading images from **Image.network(url)**, then do following in the terminal:

1. **flutter config --enable-web** // now restart ur editor
2. **flutter build web**
3. **flutter create .**
4. **flutter run**

from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error with correct indentation and the error was in the YMAL file by default has this line `publish_to: 'none'` after removing  that line. It started to output the images correctly [read more: The pubspec file](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec)

`name: ugandaclearfamilywillsuganda description: A New way of Creating your legal Wishes after death version: 1.0.0+1 environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" dependencies: flutter: sdk: flutter dev_dependencies: flutter_test: sdk: flutter flutter: uses-material-design: true assets: - images/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read assets inside package then you need to pass packageName.

```
Image.asset(
 "path",
 package: "package-name",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error as below:

Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 1 of 698 libraries in 135ms (compile: 16 ms, reload: 55 ms, reassemble: 44 ms).

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "assets/logo1.jpeg".
Exception: Asset not found

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:365:7)

#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:754:16)

#2      MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter._handleCodecReady (package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart:969:3)

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/logo1.jpeg")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#3fcab(), name: "assets/logo1.jpeg",
scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "assets/logo2.png".

Performing hot reload...
Reloaded 0 of 698 libraries in 89ms (compile: 7 ms, reload: 3 ms, reassemble: 25 ms).

So in pub spec.yaml file I changed the section of flutter as below:
flutter:

## The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is

## included with your application, so that you can use the icons in

## the material Icons class.

uses-material-design: true

## To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:
- assets/logo2.png

After hot reload it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Previously I set images paths as following

```
"assets/images/SU.jpg"
```

then I had this error so I changed it as following

```
"images/SU.jpg"
```

then it worked!!

Answer (score -1):

In this Time You are add images to assets.but not enough.you must add in **`pubspec.yaml`** (That file on your Flutter Project Folder) . Add Like this

```
flutter:
uses-material-desgin: true
assets:
    - images/img1.jpg
```

Comment: Formatting is wrong. Günter Zöchbauer answer has correct formatting.