# Flutter - Exception Caught by Image Resource Service

Tags: flutter, dart

I have just started to learn Flutter / Dart and I'm stuck in an error.

I have this:

- dart.main

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'I am Rich',
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
        body: Center(
          child: Image.asset('assets/images/diamond.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

- pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/diamond.png
```

and in my root dir I have:

[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a0i6.png)

When I run my program I got this error:

```
I/flutter (25995): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (25995): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (25995): Unable to load asset: assets/images/diamond.png
I/flutter (25995):
I/flutter (25995): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (25995): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)
I/flutter (25995): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (25995): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:668:31)
I/flutter (25995): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:651:14)
I/flutter (25995): #3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:504:13)
I/flutter (25995): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:355:22)
I/flutter (25995): #5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:502:83)
I/flutter (25995): #6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:108:19)
I/flutter (25995): #7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:333:9)
I/flutter (25995): #8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:463:26)
I/flutter (25995): (elided 13 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (25995):
I/flutter (25995): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/diamond.png")
I/flutter (25995): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#25fdf(), name:
I/flutter (25995):   "assets/images/diamond.png", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (25995): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter assets error: EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644621/flutter-assets-error-exception-caught-by-image-resource-service)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add the full path to the image in your pubspec.yaml, in this case: `assets/images/diamong.png`

I've done it that way in my projects and worked just fine.

An other thing to check is if your `assets` dir is located at the same level as `/lib` (if they are siblings), if not, you should move it to the same level.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo! I tried using your tips but nothing changed.

My `assets` dir is located at the same level as `lib` dir

Comment: This is strange. One thing that has happened to me is that the first time I include a resource (like an image for instance) I need to kill and relaunch the app to get everything synced to the device. Maybe this is whats going on in your case. Hot reload doesn't work in this case, relaunching the App is required.

Comment: Yeah, I did this already. Did not work too

Comment: I fixed it by uninstalling the app in the emulator and then `shutter clean` and `shutter run` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misspelling from your assets/images/diamong.png and the root picture you have.  I am assuming the .png should be diamond.png

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho did that fix your problem?  If not can you re-edit your question with what the new error comes up with.

Comment: I fixed it by uninstalling the app in the emulator and then shutter clean and shutter run and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure you have a diamong.png image in your **assets>images folder** with same extension i.e .png

2.If your image path is correct Try terminating & **restarting the app**.

NOTE: **Don't hot reload**. You have to restart the app to see changes.

Comment: Hi Gaurav. I did it already and nothing. 

PS.: The diamong.png was a mistake already fixed.

Comment: Have you created a sub directory in assets?

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of same?

Comment: I fixed it by uninstalling the app in the emulator and then shutter clean and shutter run and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your Terminal and write

```
flutter pub get
```

Then Run the Code

If It Wont work  then run:

```
flutter clean
```

Then Run Again . i hope it will solve your problem

Comment: i did that already Tasnuva. This command is for when we edit the pubspec.yaml right ?

Comment: Then Try to Write flutter clean , then see what happen

Comment: I fixed it by uninstalling the app in the emulator and then shutter clean and shutter run and it worked.

Comment: you are most welcome , feel free to press the upvote that will encourage us for sure

Comment: sure! Already did it. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uninstalling the app in the emulator and then `shutter clean` and `shutter run` and it worked.

[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH1vh.png)

Thanks all for the help!!!